# linphone mediastreamer2 fetcher failure while integrating with yocto

Tags: linphone

Able to do git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/mediastreamer2.git

but from bb file getting

broadband/../downloads/git2/git.linphone.org.BC.public.mediastreamer2.git'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /BC/public/mediastreamer2.git
ERROR: mediastreamer2-git_eb2af04948a1a0e0f3384f0e46c3513b0aa51e95-r0.0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://git.linphone.org/BC/public/mediastreamer2.git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

bb file contents

```
require mediastreamer2.inc

inherit gitpkgv

PR = "${INC_PR}.0"


SRCREV = "eb2af04948a1a0e0f3384f0e46c3513b0aa51e95"

SRC_URI = "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/mediastreamer2.git"
PV = "git_${SRCREV}"
PKGV = "${GITPKGVTAG}"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=c46082167a314d785d012a244748d803"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the SRC_URI by "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/mediastreamer2.git" and it should work.